# OPC Connection - HRESULT E_FAIL returned from call to COM component

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, automation, opc

I have an application I am working on in Visual Studio 2012.  I am using .NET 2.0 for this.
This application talks uses the Interop.OPCAutomation.dll OPC wrapper.  On this system, it tests and runs successfully (Windows 7 Ultimate - 64 SP1, Intel i7 processor).  When I move the source code to my server which has the same version of Visual Studio and is also Windows 7 Ultimate - 64, but is an AMD six-core and does not have SP1 yet, I get this error:

Exception:Thrown: "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component." (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
A System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was thrown: "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."
Time: 2/21/2014 7:58:03 PM
Thread:Main Thread[2256]

The line of code which is causing this:
OPCMyServer.Connect("KEPware.KEPServerEx.V4", "localhost")

This works on several machines but for some reason not on this one computer.  I have changed from .NET 2.0 to 3.0, 3.5, 4.0 but the error remains the same.  What could possibly be different on this machine that is causing this error?

I am sure I am being too vague, but I am not too familiar with these COM components outside of how I use them in the code.

Comment: have you checked the version of the COM component you are using? Maybe some dependent DLL is different that COM component needs? Have you tried testing the COM component using some other test program to verify that it works? Did it register properly (regsvr32) ?

Comment: If the Windows versions are identical, and both SP1 and updated, and have the same framework versions, I don't see what could be different.  As far as I can tell it was registered successfully.  No warnings or errors.  But for testing environment, Visual studio should handle that.

Comment: but you wrote "but is an AMD six-core and does not have SP1 yet," so they are not same then?

Comment: the processor itself is different but the installations are identical.
Problem RESOLVED:
I took the OPCDAAuto.dll out of C:\windows\syswow64\ from the good computer and copied it to the other computer.  Both file versions, dates, and sizes were identical, but I was running out of options.  I un-registered the existing one and re-registered the new one.  BINGO.  Everything is working.  I am not sure what happened, but this resolved it.